# Вопрос по реализации ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я не совсем пойму, как мне правильнее делать ViewModel.
1. Должны ли свойства быть просто оберткой над Model или же они должны быть самодостаточными и только инициализироваться при помощи Model?
2. Как лучше получать Model у ViewModel. Через метод или свойство.
Вот привожу пример:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public Int32 SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

//Свойства ViewModel являются просто оберткой над свойствами Model
public class SomeViewModel1 : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SomeModel _model;

    public SomeModel Model 
    {
        get { return _model; }
    }
    public Int32 SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _model.SomeProperty; }
        set { _model.SomeProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public SomeViewModel1(SomeModel someModel)
    {
        _model = someModel;
    }
    public SomeModel GetModel()
    {
        return _model;
    }
}

//Свойства ViewModel являются самодостаточными, инициализируются свойствами Model
public class SomeViewModel2 : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Int32 _someProperty;

    public Int32 SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set { _someProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public SomeModel Model
    {
        get { return GetModel(); }
    }

    public SomeViewModel2(SomeModel model)
    {
        _someProperty = model.SomeProperty;
    }
    public SomeModel GetModel()
    {
        SomeModel model = new SomeModel();
        model.SomeProperty = SomeProperty;
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не существует правильного решения с классами типа `SomeViewModel`. Общего, подходящего на все случаи жизни, простого рецепта нет. Правильное решение зависит от конкретной семантики. Покажите, как _на самом деле_ называются ваши классы, и что они _на самом деле_ делают.

Comment: У меня есть ViewModel задачи, имеющая свойства, описывающее выданное время для таймера. На экране мне надо отображать текущую задачу и оставшееся время. Если я буду для отображения времени изменять время в ней, то следующему человеку достанется меньше времени :-) И вот у меня вопрос, либо копировать Model, либо ViewModel самодостаточен.

Comment: @Vlad Напиши то-же самое в ответе, что бы я это пометил как ответ. Меня он полностью устроил. А то чего вопрос будет не отвеченный висеть.

Comment: Посмотрите, вот [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/10105) довольно подробный ответ на эту же тему. Если он вам подходит, можно отметить дубликатом.

Comment: @Vlad Да, мне тот ответ очень нравится. Можно отметить, как дубликат.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Иерархические модели, вложенные модели, коллекции моделей, правильность понимания паттерна](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/379255/%d0%98%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8)