# C# MVVM (WPF). как использовать Model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте, попрошу помочь с пониманием использования MVVM патерна.
Как представляю я его для себя:

1. Существует отдельный самодостаточный проект (или библиотека) в котором написан какой - то готовый функционал. Пользователю проекта предоставляется интерфейс в котором открыты свойства который определяют состояние сервиса и открыты события для оповещения сервисом (push/pull notification). Например для нотификации использовать ReactiveExt.
2. Стоит задача использовать этот сервис, написать для него UI.
   Создаем новый WPF проект, для облегчения поддержки MVVM используем какой-нибудь фреймворк (я использую Caliburn.Micro).
3. Создаем связку View-ViewModel. Используем Binding, code behind стараемся не использовать (используем только для функционала замкнутого на View).
4. Отлаживаем отдельно UI-ый проект. Проверяем работу всех нотификаций, байндинга и т.д.
5. Имеем 2 готовых не связанных проекта. Сервис и UI.
6. Дальше... Самое простое получить экземпляр сервиса во ViewModel ( создать напрямую, передать в конструкторе, получить через DI). И подписать обработчики события на события сервиса. В теле обработчиков использовать свойства ViewModel которые участвуют в байндинге. Также ViewModel обращается за состоянием сервиса к открытым свойствам сервиса.   Таким образом работа сервиса будет связанна с UI.

А где Model в этой структуре?

Если сделать Mapping сервиса на объект Model. Т.е. копия сервиса имеющая только нужные для UI свойства. И уже получать экземпляр модели во ViewModel.

Но ведь тогда придется дублировать и события (нотификацию).

Тут я немного запутался)))... 
Подскажите где же Model???

Comment: Model вам в этом случае в явном виде не нужна, она у вас остается "черным ящиком" взаимодействие с которым происходит через ваш Сервис. Сервис служит т.н. `Façade`, а что за ним вам по большому счету должно быть все равно.

Comment: Спасибо, примерно так я и думал. А что если мы получаем данные из базы данных (через ORM например) и если использовать напрямую сущности БД для байндинга, то тогда появятся observable коллекции в самих сущностях слоя Domen.Т.е. мы UI залезем в другой слой. Здесь думаю явно нужен маппинг полученных из БД данных. я прав? и как лучше поступать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы всё правильно описываете. Сервис — это и есть ваша модель.

Если вы считаете, что у сервиса свойства, готовые для отображения в UI, это чаще всего не так. Например, модель живёт в непонятно каком потоке (а то и в нескольких, как ей удобно), а VM должна жить в UI-потоке. VM должна выставлять `INotifyPropertyChanged`, а ваша модель выставляет Rx. Ну и вам наверняка не нужны *все* свойства вашего сервиса, а некоторые, возможно, вы хотите объединить или преобразовать как вам больше подходит для UI.

Да, это может быть некоторым дубляжом кода. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/10105) немного больше по этой же теме.

Comment: Спасибо VladD, теперь увереннее буду использовать MVVM)

Comment: @Aldmi: Пожалуйста! Буду рад, если помогло разобраться.