# Как прибиндить List в MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть модель пользователя, в которой находится список сообщений этого пользователя.

```
class User
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public List<string> Messages {get;set;}
}
```

В интерфейсе мы можем просматривать, редактировать и удалять эти сообщения.

Сейчас в `UsersVM` я добавил `ObservableCollection<string> Messages` и когда срабатывает команда редактирования или удаления, то фиксирую эти изменения как в `UsersVM.Messages`, так и в модели `User.Messages`, что не очень правильно, как мне кажется.

Подскажите, как сделать правильнее?

Comment: А почему вам кажется, что это не очень правильно?

Comment: @VladD, то, что модель реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged`, полагаю

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Окей, а что в этом плохого? Модель имеет право делать так, как ей вздумается, на то она и модель.

Comment: @VladD нарушает классическое `MVVM`, но сам ничего плохого не вижу в том, что бы не следовать всем требованиям.

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Эээ, и в чём же нарушение классического MVVM?

Comment: @VladD, @FoggyFinder, Нет, модель не реализует интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Модель я оставил такую же, как указал в вопросе. А вот уже во `ViewModel` я добавил `ObservableCollection` и привязываюсь к ней. И получается, что данные я добавляю в 2 коллекции вместо одной: и в модель, и в VM. То есть в принципе так делать вполне нормально?

Comment: @maxwell: Проблем с этим не вижу. Посмотрите, например, тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/10105

Comment: @VladD скопирую ваш ответ `Модель пишется в отрыве от реализации MVVM...Модель не знает ни о VM, ни тем более о View, и тем самым независима и может быть легко использована в другом проекте.`. Изменение`List<_>` на `ObservableCollection<_> ` ради обновления интерфейса, на мой взгляд, неправильно.

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Ага, понял, модель должна _хоть как-то_ сообщать о своих изменениях. Через INotifyCollectionChanged или как угодно ещё, это её задача по идее.

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Так что каким бы образом модель не сообщала о своих изменениях, это всё равно правильно. По-моему, так.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, дублировать данные не рационально. Реализуйте интерфейс [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

На самом деле сделать это может быть не так просто, но, благо, есть доступ к [исходным кодам `ObservableCollection`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs)

Как видно, в основе этого класса лежит `Collection<T>`:

> Класс Collection также имеет конструктор, который принимает существующую реализацию IList. В отличие от других классов коллекций, передаваемый
>   список не копируется, а для него создается прокси, а это значит, что последующие изменения будут отражаться в оболочке Collection (хотя и без запуска виртуальных
>   методов Collection). И наоборот, изменения, внесенные через Collection,
>   будут воздействовать на лежащий в основе список.

Таким образом, мы можем скопировать реализацию `ObservableCollection` и добавить в нее примерно такой конструктор (заменить существующий(-е)):

```
public ObservableCollection(IList<T> list) : base(list)
{ }
```

Это позволит пользоваться уже готовой коллекцией модели, без дублирования и, в то же время, всеми преимуществами `ObservableCollection`

Comment: А можете привести пример для данного случая, как в ответе? Сделайте ваш ответ более информативным.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, обновил ответ.

Comment: Отлично, а скажите, а не проще ли унаследоваться от `ObservableCollection`, чем таскать с собой почти полный дубль её исходного кода?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, к сожалению ваш вариант не сработает, так как `Collection.Items` не имеет сеттера и единственный вариант присвоить приватному полю `items` ссылку на свой `IList` - вызов конструктора `Collection(IList<T> list)`. В дочернем же `ObservableCollection` функционал переопределен и там используется копирование из одного списка в другой, а не копирование ссылки на список.

Comment: Можно унаследоваться и добавить приватный сеттер для `Collection.Items`, где с помощью рефлексии будут устанавливаться значения приватному полю `items`.

Comment: Надеюсь, я верно понимаю вашу логику, потому что кода вы привели только для добавления конструктора.

Comment: Ну я ничего плохого не вижу в том, чтобы таскать за собой нужный класс в 200 строчек. Вы ведь таскаете за собой, например, mvvm framework или другие полезные наработки. А вот через рефлесию это уже не красиво. Ну тут еще вина разработчиков фреймворка, в том что они скрыли такой полезный функционал, как прокси-коллекция.