# Привязка ListBox к переменой в другом потоке

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть экземпляр класса в другом потоке, это сервер который имеет изменяющийся список клиентов. Как привязать этот список клиентов к компоненту в окне?
**Framework 3.5**

Пытался передать компонент как параметр в поток или ссылку в конструктор, но не вышло. (Инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю, методу...)

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            serverThread = new Thread(server.Start);
            serverThread.Start();
        }

        AsynchronousIoServer server = new AsynchronousIoServer(46484);
        Thread serverThread;

        public void AddToList()
        {
            clientsListBox.Add(); //THIS ListBox
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class AsynchronousIoServer
    {
        private Socket _serverSocket;
        private int _port;

        public AsynchronousIoServer(int port)
        {
            _port = port;
        }

        public class ConnectionInfo
        {
            public Socket Socket;
            public byte[] Buffer;
        }

        private List<ConnectionInfo> _connections = new List<ConnectionInfo>(); // THIS LIST

        public void Start()
        {
            while (true)
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), _serverSocket);
        }

        private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo();
            try
            {
                Socket s = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
                connection.Socket = s.EndAccept(result);
                connection.Buffer = new byte[255];
                lock (_connections) _connections.Add(connection);
                connection.Socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connection);
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), result.AsyncState);
            }
        //code
    }
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите. Вы ведь пользуетесь MVVM, да?

Список серверов — это модельный объект. Он живёт в своём потоке, и у вас там есть список. Привязываться к модельным объектам *нельзя*, потому что они [бегут где угодно и выставляют наружу что им угодно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/10105).

Вы должны построить VM-класс, соответствующий списку серверов. В простейшем случае это может быть просто `ObservableCollection<string>`, но, скорее всего, вам понадобится вместо `string` что-то более сложное (ещё один VM-класс, описывающий *один* сервер).

Затем, ваша модель должна как-то сообщать об изменениях списка серверов. Например, выставлять `event` `ServerAdded` и `ServerRemoved`. VM должна подписаться на этот event, и, поскольку он приходит в непонятно каком потоке, вызвать процедуру добавления в список VM-серверов в UI-потоке (например, через `BeginInvoke`).

А ваш View пускай привязывается к VM-списку обыкновенным способом, через `ItemsSource`.