# C# WPF MVVM Привязка DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

привет есть код

**ViewModel**

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    JournalContext context  = new JournalContext();
    List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
    public StudentViewModel()
    {
        Students.AddRange(context.Students.Include(g => g.Parent));
    }
 }
```

**View**

```
<TabControl Name="Journal" BorderThickness="0">
            <TabItem Name="Students" DataContext="{StaticResource Student}"
                     BorderThickness="0" 
                     Style="{StaticResource NotBorder}" 
                     Background="Transparent"
                     Height="50"
                     Width="200">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="Студенты" 
                                   FontSize="30"
                                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" BorderThickness="0">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

Привязываю DataContext через ресурс

```
DataContext="{StaticResource Student}"
```

Ресурс определен в App.xaml

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/TabPanel.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ViewModel:StudentViewModel x:Key="Student"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
```

Так проблема в том что не работает.Подскажите как правильно

Comment: Это даст кое какое представление, что и как должно быть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/379255/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8/379331#379331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привязка работает только с публичными свойствами, а у вас `List<Student> Students` приватное поле.