# WPF MVVM паттерн

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model, viewmodel

Можете подробно, просто и ясно пояснить реализацию данного паттерна. Сколько уже перечитал литературы на эту тему. Суть я понял, но когда дело доходит до реализации, тут тупик , не знаю, как правильно организовать model  и ViewModel. С представлением вроде все более-менее понятно(файл xaml- наш внешний вид приложения). Вот к примеру у меня есть пару условных классов:

```
public class Test
    {
        private string testName;
        public string TestName
        {
            get { return testName; }

           set
            {
                testName = value;
            }
        }

        public List<Question> QuestionList = new List<Question>();

        public List<Answer> AnswerList = new List<Answer>();

        public int Time { get; set; }

        public int QuestCount { get; set; }
    }


 public class Question
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

    }

 public class Answer{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int VariantID { get; set; }
    }
```

Я так понимаю это и есть модель данных, но вот вопрос, у этого класса есть списки ответов и вопросов, которые тоже является объектами одноименных классов. Их выделять в отдельные модели каждый , и потом объединять в ViewModel или как? И как организовывать саму ViewModel? Буду очень благодарен за пояснение.

Comment: Посмотрите сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/379255/10105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модель это логики + данные. Т.е. в идеале вся бизнеслогики должна работать только в этом слое и знать ничего не должна о своем отображении. 
Иными словами пишите консольное приложение - полностью функциональное, только не надо писать всякие вводы выводы консольные - а уже поверх наворачиваете вьюмодели и вьюхи.

Так что да - все модели придется оборачивать в вьюмодели.

Определим базовый класс для вьюмоделей:

```
public class ViewModelBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Тогда вьюмодель для `Question` будет:

```
public class QuestionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Question _question;
    private int _id;
    private string _text;

    public QuestionViewModel(Question question)
    {
        _question = question;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _question.ID; }
        set { _question.ID = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _question.Text; }
        set { _question.Text = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

Допустим у вас есть коллекция `QuestionModelsCollection` из базы или еще откуда

То во вьмодели формы будет коллекция

```
 public ObservableCollection<QuestionViewModel> Questions {get;set;}
```

И инициализирован она может как-то так:

```
Questions = new ObservableCollection<QuestionViewModel>(QuestionModelsCollection.Select(x=> new QuestionViewModel(x));
```

К этому уже привязывайте вьюху. 
Естественно, паттерн - это не закон, а рекомендация, не всегда есть смысл разделять - когда нужно отобразить какую-то статичную информацию - над которой не будет каких-то манипуляций проводится - можно и сырую коллекцию моделей привязать. К тому же это один из множеств способов. По ситуации надо смотреть как лучше будет в том или ином случае.

Итак, у нас затруднение со вложенными моделями.

Например у нас будет такая модель:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers {get;set;}
}
```

Тогда:

```
public class QuestionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Question _question;
    public ObservableCollextion<AnswerViewModel> Answers{get;set;}

    public QuestionViewModel(Question question)
    {
        _question = question;
        Answers = new ObservableCollection<AnswerViewModel>(_question.Answers.Select(x=> new AnswerViewModel(x));
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _question.Text; }
        set { _question.Text = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Выходит каждый класс к примеру Test или же Question это отдельная модель?  И как организовать модель Test , если она содержит в себе объекты других классов?

Comment: Аналогично. внутри конструктора оборачивать вложенные модели.

Comment: Немного не понял, к примеру у класс TestModel есть свойства Name, Time и тд. И в конструктор TestModel передавать QuestionModel? Точнее список этих объектов?

Comment: В конструктор вьюмодели - передается модельный объект - со всеми потрахами - то что вы написали вообще не понятно что - зачем вы пытаетесь одну модель в другую запихать?

Comment: Аа, тоесть модели по сути никак не связаны, даже если одна по логике содержит другую, и они связываются во вьюмоделе, правильно?

Comment: Я кажется понял в чем проблема. сейчас я напишу в ответе как в таком случае надо сделать.

Comment: @Ага - готово. Смотрите.

Comment: О , так понятнее, понял как работать с вложенными моделями, большое спасибо вам

Comment: @Ага, примите в таком случае ответ)