# Как правильно разнести Событие по разным файлам?

Tags: c#, события

Есть статический Класс который выполняет определенный набор действий и информирует через события о ходе свой работы тех кто подписан на него. Этот класс не зависит от других классов, кроме того в котором объявлены EventArg. Таких классов несколько и они разбиты на отдельные dll.

```
public static class OperatoinManager
    {
        // Событие возникающее при ошибки
        public static event Action<ProcessingEventArgs> ErrorHappend;

        // Информационное событие, возникающее при работе программы
        public static event Action<ProcessingEventArgs> Done;

        // Тайминговое событие, возникающее при работе программы
        public static event Action<TimingArgs> TimingEvent;


        public static void Execute(Document doc, IEnumerable<Element> firstSet, IEnumerable<Element> secondSet, Operation op)
        {
            using (Transaction tx = new Transaction(doc))
            {
                Stopwatch watch_cmd = new Stopwatch();
                tx.Start($"Batch {op}");
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var firstElement in firstSet)
                {
                    foreach (var secondElement in secondSet)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                            Done?.Invoke(new ProcessingEventArgs(new List<Element> { firstElement, secondElement }, $"{op} Done!"));
                            ++i;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ErrorHappend?.Invoke(new ProcessingEventArgs(new List<Element> { firstElement, secondElement }, ex.Message));
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                tx.Commit();
                TimingEvent?.Invoke(new TimingArgs(op.ToString(), watch_cmd ));
            }
        }
    }
```

Есть нестатический класс (VievModel для формы) через который в WPF окне отображается инфа по ходу исполнения программы. Этот класс так же не зависим от других , кроме того в котором объявлены EventArgs. Он идет как отдельная dll, которой может не быть.

```cs
    public class ViewModelDockablePanelLogger : DependencyObject
    {
        public ViewModelDockablePanelLogger()
        {
        }

        public string LogInfo
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LogInfoProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LogInfoProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LogInfo.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LogInfoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LogInfo", typeof(string), typeof(ViewModelDockablePanelLogger), new PropertyMetadata(""));


        public string ErrorInfo
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ErrorInfoProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ErrorInfoProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ErrorInfo.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorInfoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ErrorInfo", typeof(string), typeof(ViewModelDockablePanelLogger), new PropertyMetadata(""));



        public string TimingInfo
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TimingInfoProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TimingInfoProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TimingInfo.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TimingInfoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TimingInfo", typeof(string), typeof(ViewModelDockablePanelLogger), new PropertyMetadata(""));


        public void OnDone(ProcessingEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            LogInfo = LogInfo.Insert(0, $"Elements: {eventArgs.Elements[0].Id}, {eventArgs.Elements[1].Id}, {eventArgs.Message}\n");
        }

        public void OnErrorHappened(ProcessingEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            ErrorInfo = ErrorInfo.Insert(0, $"{eventArgs.Elements[0].Id}, {eventArgs.Elements[1].Id}, {eventArgs.Message}.\n\n");
        }

        public void OnTimingEvent(TimingArgs eventArgs)
        {
            TimingInfo = $"{eventArgs.Operation} processing time {eventArgs.Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.\n";
        }
    }
```

Есть класс в котором находится точка входа, из него происходит вызов всего остального и проверяется наличие dll. Если эта dll найдена, то происходит подписка ViewModel на события.

```
    public class Ribbon : IExternalApplication
    {
        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Describe paths for all assemblies that include to the project
            /// </summary>
            string pathCurrent = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string location = pathCurrent.Substring(0, pathCurrent.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            string pathBatchOperations = location + "DEA.BatchOperations.dll";
            string pathDockPanel = location + "DEA.DockPanel.dll";
            string pathCommonTools = location + "DEA.CommonTools.dll";

            /// <summary>
            /// Create Ribbon tab
            /// </summary>
            string RibbonPanelName = "DEA";
            a.CreateRibbonTab(RibbonPanelName);

            #region Ribbon panel Batch Operations
            /// <summary>
            /// Create Ribbon panel for Batch operations commands
            /// </summary>

            if (File.Exists(pathBatchOperations))
            {
            ....
            }

            #endregion

            #region Ribbon Tab Settings and Dockable Panel
            /// <summary>
            /// Create Ribbon panel for Settings
            /// </summary>

            if (File.Exists(pathDockPanel))
            {
                RibbonPanel SettingsPanel = a.CreateRibbonPanel(RibbonPanelName, "Settings");

                PushButtonData pushButtonHideDockableWindow = new PushButtonData("HideDockable", "Hide Dockable", pathDockPanel, "DEA.DockPanel.Model.ShowHideDockableWindow");
                pushButtonHideDockableWindow.LargeImage = GetImage(Resources.fuckOff.GetHbitmap());
                RibbonItem ri1 = SettingsPanel.AddItem(pushButtonHideDockableWindow);

                MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
                DockablePaneId paneId = new DockablePaneId(new Guid("4cf41110-46c3-4fd9-a65f-d548201555fd"));
                a.RegisterDockablePane(paneId, RibbonPanelName, (IDockablePaneProvider)mainPage);

                  /// В ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ НУЖНО ВЫПОЛНИТЬ ПОДПИСКУ 
                  /// Что то вроде этого:
                OperatoinManager.Done += ViewModelDockablePanelLogger.OnDone;
                OperatoinManager.ErrorHappend += ViewModelDockablePanelLogger.OnErrorHappened;
                OperatoinManager.TimingEvent += ViewModelDockablePanelLogger.OnTimingEvent;

            }
            #endregion

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
}
```

Вопрос в том что нельзя, и наверное, неправильно обратится к экземпляру класса ViewModel из вне.   Включать в сборку ссылки на те классы которые генерируют события так же не получится, потому что тогда придется дублировать проверку наличия dll файлов и в классе с окном и в главном классе.

Comment: Не надо слов, если у вас вопрос по коду - покажите код.

Comment: `Есть нестатический Класс` ... `public static class OperatoinManager` ?

Comment: по поводу правильно / не правильно, тут много к чему есть вопросы. Например, зачем вам статический `OperatoinManager`?  Вот это вот `ViewModelDockablePanelLogger ` ну никак не похожа на ViewModel, это вообще похоже на элемент интерфейса. Вот это `Ribbon : IExternalApplication` вообще не ясно что такое. Скажем так, MVVM у вас тут нет, у вас какие то раскиданные классы, которые вы пытаетесь связать воедино.

Comment: OperatoinManager я сделал статическим потому что этот класс просто выполняет несколько операций над объектами и ничего не хранит в себе.. ViewModelDockablePanelLogger просто подготавливает информацию для вывода в textBox, разве это должно содержаться во View? Ribbon : IExternalApplication: то что я пытаюсь написать не отдельное приложение, а плагин для программы Revit. Ribbon - должен выглядить именно так - это требование API. Этот класс генерирует дополнительную панель с кнопками. К каждой кнопке привязана одна команда. Функционал, наверное, можно отнести к View.

Comment: Думаю сперва сделать все в соответствии с шаблоном MVVM постараться, а потом вернуться к событиям и их привязке. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Возможно посоветуете какой то ресурс где прочитать про MVVM и другие паттерны подробно

Comment: `OperatoinManager я сделал статическим потому что этот класс просто выполняет несколько операций над объектами и ничего не хранит в себе` это ваше первое заблуждение. Этот класс хранит в себе события, а события хранят ссылки на всех подписавшихся. Потому у вас тут не только статический класс с состоянием, но и потенциальная утечка памяти (если вы подпишетесь на событие и не отпишитесь, то статический класс не даст GC убить подписавшийся класс, так как он держит ссылку на него)

Comment: `ViewModelDockablePanelLogger просто подготавливает информацию для вывода в textBox, разве это должно содержаться во View` вы назали какой то класс `ViewModel`, но фактически к понятию `ViewModel` этот класс отношения не имеет. Он содержит в себе свойства зависимостей и какие то методы, которые никакой `ViewModel` по определению не нужны

Comment: По поводу почитать про MVVM - пользуйтесь поисковиками, информации вагон, не тратье чужое время на то, что можете сделать сами. Вот я гуглил 10 секунд, нашел сразу: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/179763), [два](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php), [три](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm), [четыре](https://www.wintellect.com/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained/)