# Многопоточность в в C# и WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как реализовать многопоточность в WPF? Нужно сделать программу, которая при поступлении данных на COM порт меняет видео в программе на другое, случайно выбранное из доступных. Суть в том, что бы запустить во втором потоке цикл, который будет читать данные с com порта и менять видео в программе, т.к. когда я просто вхожу в цикл программа просто крашается.

Вот мой код:

```
OptionsWindow optionsWindow;

    SerialPort myPort;
    int timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myPort = new SerialPort();

        playerMediaElement.Source = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Videos\0.mp4", UriKind.Absolute);

        playerMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        playerMediaElement.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

        playerMediaElement.Play();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("portOptions.txt", Encoding.Default))
        {
            myPort.PortName = sr.ReadLine();
            myPort.BaudRate = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            timer = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    private void PlayerMediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        playerMediaElement.Stop();
        playerMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.P)
        {
            optionsWindow = new OptionsWindow();
            optionsWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

Нужно выполнять эту функцию в новом потоке или асинхронно (главное, что бы программа не крашилась)

```
void TestOnNewLog()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (myPort.ReadLine() != null) MessageBox.Show("Пришли новые данные!");
        }
    }
```

Я искал в интернете материал на эту тему, но не помогало... Если кто то знает прошу помочь

Comment: `Суть в том, что бы запустить во втором потоке цикл, который будет читать данные с com порта и менять видео в программе, т.к. когда я просто вхожу в цикл программа просто крашается.` ну дак и вперед, в чем проблема то?

Comment: Нужно в новом потоке бесконечный цикл запускать

Comment: ну так запускайте, какие с этим проблемы?

Comment: Не знаю как, я новичок в C#...

Comment: Не важно, новичек или не новичек. У вас же поисковик есть - разве проблема найти там ответ на такой базовый вопрос - это же не что то особенное - запуск потока, это штатный функционал, это гуглится за 2 секунды. Вот если бы вы что то попробовали и у вас не вышло - это да, потянуло бы на вопрос, а сейчас вы просто хотите, чтобы кто то загуглил инфу за вас.

Comment: вот вам [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8), вот неплохая [статья по потокам](http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml), в следующий раз, пожалуйста, попытайтесь как то самостоятельно решить свою проблему перед тем, как спрашивать, не тратье впустую чужое время.

Comment: если интересно, как я те ссылки нашел, просто загуглил `c# thread` и потыкал в результаты поиска.

Comment: Извиняюсь за неудобства, в следущий раз постараюсь сразу идти в гугл, если хочешь напиши ответ на вопрос и я отмечу, как верный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам по себе запуск потока - задача тривиальная. Как я уже скаазал, вы примеры можете найти в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8) или просто [поиском в интернете](http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml).

Однако, вы должны понимать, что в WPF есть понятие главного UI потока и всё взаимодействие с элементами пользовательского интерфейса должно происходить строго через UI поток.

Возникает вопрос: вот запустили вы свой код в фоновом потоке, и вам надо что то обновить в интерфейсе программы. Как это сделать? Для этого существует диспетчер. Вы можете попросить диспетчер выполнить код в UI потоке.

Как это работает: Например, я создам поток, который посчитает до 100, и при этом будет выводить значение счетчика на экран:

```
public class MyWnd : Window
{
    private TextBlock tb;

    public MyWnd()
    {
        tb = new TextBlock() { Width = 300 };
        tb.FontSize = 72;
        this.Content = tb;
        this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;

        var thread = new Thread(Worker) { IsBackground = true };
        thread.Start();
    }


    private void Worker(object state)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var t = i.ToString();
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { tb.Text = t; });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Как запустить

```
new MyWnd().ShowDialog();
```

Результат

[image: ...]

Остается только отметить, что описанный здесь подход хорошо работает на небольших приложениях, но если вы что то более-менее серьезное пишете, то вам стоит обратить внимание на [MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/179763) паттерн.

Вот небольшой пример. Определим простую команду

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute.Invoke(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}
```

Наша ViewModel будет содежать значение и всю логику по управлению потоками

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand StartCommand { get; }
    public ICommand StopCommand { get; }


    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (value == _value) return;
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Thread _thread;
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        StartCommand = new DelegateCommand((p) =>
            {
                _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _thread = new Thread(Worker) { IsBackground = true };
                _thread.Start(_tokenSource.Token);
            },
            p => _thread == null);

        StopCommand = new DelegateCommand(p =>
        {
            _tokenSource.Cancel();
            _tokenSource = null;
            _thread = null;
        }, p => _thread != null);
    }

    private void Worker(object state)
    {
        var token = (CancellationToken)state;
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Value++;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Тут все просто - 2 команды, на старт и стоп, и запуск / остановка потока.

Далее, представление будет вот такое

```
<Window x:Class="RU_1018395.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RU_1018395"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyViewModel x:Key="viewmodel"></local:MyViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource viewmodel}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
            <Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}">Start</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding StopCommand}">Stop</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock FontSize="72" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

В представлении я положил ViewModel как ресурс и далее натянул эту ViewModel на грид. 
Кстати, можно заметить, что я нигде не использовал диспетчер - всё потому, что я использую привязки для передачи данных между ViewModel и View, а они уже сами понимают, как рабоать с UI потоком.

Ну и результат

[image: ...]

С одной стороны может показаться, что второй пример более сложный, но на самом деле мы отделили логику от представления и избежали мешанины, которая у вас в примере в конструкторе главной формы.