# Обязательства при работе с модель во вью-модели

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, вот я создал где-то модель и передаю во вью-модель.

Передо мной есть какие-то обязательства (соглашения), что я должен работать с тем, что было передано в конструктор?

Или скажем, мне ничего не запрещает внутри сделать свою копию, а снаружи ВМ'а сделать метод ExportToModel, если родительская форма, после закрытия дочерней хочет работать с результатами?

Comment: Делайте так как удобно, никаких обязательств

Comment: Где только не приходилось размещать методы типа ExportToModel - и в отдельных классах / экстеншенах и выносить в отдельную сборку, чтобы не захламлять контракты некоторыми особенностями реализации. Проекты разные, требования разные -- делайте по обстоятельствам.

Comment: Немного по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/10105. / VM вовсе не обязана один в один повторять структуру данных модели. Иногда так делают, но в более-менее сложных случаях M- и VM-классы получаются совсем разными.